# What is the use of aware/capable interfaces in php?

Tags: php, symfony, interface

I see these interfaces in Symfony and sometimes other projects. Usually they only hold a setter and a getter and they class that implements that must implement the method from the interface.

I don't see the added value here though. Why not simply add the method instead of having 4-5 implements because you want to add aware and capable interfaces to an existing class.

Yes you might easily see what a class is able to do but you can also see this based on the methods and it gives you a whole lot more interfaces that(in my eyes) do not really add something.

Could somebody explain to me why people are using these in PHP? I know they might have a place in Java(I think it originates from Spring?). But I am not seeing the value here.

Comment: This sounds like you're asking what the value of interfaces in general are.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Typehinting against an interface and re-usability/decoupling from concrete implementations is something entirely different. I see the value in general interfaces. I do not see the value in hooking up 4-5 interfaces to build up a class.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify. I don't know what an "aware" or "capable" interface is supposed to represent, but when you said "why not simply add the method...", that sounded like someone arguing against using interfaces in general. Nvm if that's not the case.

Comment: Interfaces are useful, independently of the language used. We can't really told you if having that many interface is useful or not because that depend of the architecture you have, the size of your project and its goal of maintenability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of the Symfony framework, the ContainerAwareInterface is used to "flag" a class as needing the container.  In particular, controllers can optionally implement the interface.

What happens is that when a controller is instantiated by the request handler,the container is injected if the controller implements the interface.  Bit of a hack perhaps but in practice, using interfaces to specially process certain groups of classes works well.  Just be sure to document.

I should also point out that later versions of the framework provide a ContainerAwareTrait which removes the need to actually implement the setContainer method.

Answer (score -2):

Try to think an interface as a blueprint, that describes your class.

The main reason we use an interface is that it gives as the ability to swap implementations.

When a class implements an interface it signs a contract that it must provide these methods that are defined in your interface. Let's say that two classes implement this particular interface. Now they signed a contract that they will provide these methods. So far so good. Now a term you might hear often is program to an interface. If 2 classes implement a contract we can swap them at will. Consider the below example.

```
interface CarInterface
{
    public function hasName();
    public function hasEngine();
    public function accelerate();
}

class toyota{
    public function hasName(){
    //implementation
    }

    public function hasEngine(){
    //implementation
    }

    public function accelerate(){
    //implementation
    }
}

class opel{
    public function hasName(){
    //implementation
    }

    public function hasEngine(){
    //implementation
    }

    public function accelerate(){
    //implementation
    }
}
```

now we can have one class that needs a car.

```
class circuit{

protected $car;

public function __construct(CarInterface $car)
    {
        $this->car=$car;
    }

public function startRace(){
    $this->car->accelerate();
}


}
```

Ok, we are set to go.Imagine we have to instatiate the class circuit. We have to pass an object to that new instance, but which object ? ANY object that implements the interface. Because we typecasted it, we programmed to an interface not to a concrete implementation.

```
$circuit = new circuit(new toyota);
$circuit->startRace();
```

later we need to change it, because we need a circuit to run our opel car. No problem.

```
$circuit = new circuit(new opel);
$circuit->startRace();
```

We are able to swap implementations at will because we programmed to an interface. This is the main benefit. Please read about the subjects I talk here, it is difficult to wrap your head around this concepts, but once you do you use them all the time. Hope it is a bit more clear now.

Comment: This is not about interfaces in general. It is more about composition vs inheritance and why somebody would implement multiple interfaces vs a single one.

Comment: Plus, it has nothing to do with the question.